# popup.html - change width?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

How do I change the width of popup.html? I've attempted changing the width of the div in it but that seems to have no effect.

Here is what I've tried...

```
<div id='poppingup' style = "min-width: 300px; display:none">
```

Comment: change it to `<div id='poppingup' style = "width: 300px; display:none">` min-width sets the min width

Comment: Disregard comment I erased. It worked, that and I was doing something else stupid. Make your reply an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 79):

Popup width is determined by the visible content, so either make your div visible or apply `min-width` to `body`:

```
body {
    min-width:300px;
}
```

(there is also a limit on max width, I think it is 800px)

Comment: For including `max-width` **+1**. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @RotimiBest Thanks, but I didn't mean the CSS property. I meant Google's documentation detailing that the limit on max width is 800px, as I couldn't find them referencing that anywhere.

Comment: @KasparLee Okay I see. The closest is a final answer on chrome forum: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/nJIWEuJpI3Y

Comment: Here's the source code that mentions the max width (800px) and height (600px):
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/views/extensions/extension_popup.h;l=60;bpv=0;bpt=1

Answer (score 17):

I tried to change the width of body too, but it didn't work. You can set the width of html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="min-width:600px;">
```

It worked in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the css didn't work for me.

You can do it with javascript:

```
<script>
window.resizeTo(1920, 768);
</script>
```

Or if you want to accomodate all screen sizes:

```
<script>
var newheight = window.height * (5/10);
var newwidth = window.width * (7/10);
window.resizeTo(newheight, newwidth);
</script>
```

Comment: You did see the answer about how to change the css?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using

> popup.css

file for styling so inside this CSS file i have done the following code as per the popup size requirement and it works for me.

```
html
{
    width: 1000px; /* max: 1000px */
    height: 750px; /* max: 750px */
}
```